# Group by a nested list of object based on date

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, lambda

Hi guys i have a class like this :

```
   public class supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
    {
        public string date { set; get; }
        public List<string> questionList { set; get; }
        public List<string> answerList { set; get; }
    }
```

I have a query that returns the list of this class

```
     List<PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres> temp
            = dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
                       .Where(i => i.StudentNum == studentNumber && i.username==objstu.Return_SupervisorUserName_By_StudentNumber(studentNumber))
                       .ToList() // <-- This will bring the data into memory.
                       .Select(i => new PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
                           {
                               answerList = Return_Answer_List(studentNumber,i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date),
                               questionList = Return_Question_List(studentNumber, i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date),
                               date = ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
                           })
                       .OrderByDescending(i => i.date)
                       .ToList();
```

So i need to group my list **temp** by **date** and select all 3 column again i mean date,questionlist,answerlist.

I just want to grouping my result after executing this query 
I am using linq asp.net visual 2012

Comment: Why do you have `date` in `string` type, why not `DateTime` ?

Comment: What is your question? If you're asking us to determine what the query is, what have you tried? Don't expect us just to do all the work for you. Show some effort...

Comment: Because i have to convert it to transfer to another layer

Comment: No i have the query i just want how can i group my result of query

Comment: possible duplicate of [combine OrderBy and Group by in lambda expression makes an error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104300/combine-orderby-and-group-by-in-lambda-expression-makes-an-error)

Comment: @GertArnold No i change my query ,

Comment: I don't want to use group by command in my query syntax,i want to separate that from the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var temp
        = dbconnect.tblAnswerLists
                   .Where(i => i.StudentNum == studentNumber && i.username==objstu.Return_SupervisorUserName_By_StudentNumber(studentNumber))
                   .ToList() // <-- This will bring the data into memory.
                   .Select(i => new PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres
                       {
                           answerList = Return_Answer_List(studentNumber,i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date),
                           questionList = Return_Question_List(studentNumber, i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date),
                           date = ConvertToPersianToShow(i.dateOfAnswer.Value.Date)
                       })
                   .GroupBy(i => i.date)
                   .OrderByDescending(i => i.Key)
                   .ToList();
```

`temp` will actually be of type `List<IGrouping<string, PresentClass.supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres>>`.

Comment: So i have to return --supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres-- list

Comment: If you just return a flat list of `supervisorAnswerQuesttionPres`, how do you know what the groups are?